# Не загружается пользовательский файл

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Первый раз столкнулся с необходимостью загрузить файл во Flask на сервер из браузера , но почему-то он не передается. Делаю вот что, в шаблоне пишу вот такую форму:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file">
    <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>
```

В коде пытаюсь получить длину списка с загруженными файлами:

```
@app.route('/some', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def file():
if request.method == 'POST':        
    f = len(request.files)
    return str(f)
```

Такая конструкция возвращает на страницу 0, соответственно request.files пустой. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: name для инпута не прописали

Comment: точно( спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы request возвращал не пустой словарь, необходимо в теге `input` указать `name="любое вменяемое имя"`:

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/some">
        <input type="file" name="upfile1">
        <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
```

таким образом, к конкретному файлу Вы сможете получить доступ через ключ, указанный в поле `name`:

```
request.files['upfile1']
```